# How to access remote folder using http in java through cross context?

Tags: java, file, tomcat7, contextpath

Below is the snippet :

```
 File folder = new File("http://10.155.6.108:9292/downloads/EA0005632_000000000/");
            File file[] = folder.listFiles();
```

And Context is defined in server.xml file of `tomcat 7` on remote system `10.155.6.108`.It is windows.

```
<Context docBase="E:/EAPP_BSLI_TAB_DOCS" crossContext="true" path="/downloads" />
```

I am able to download the image when I enter this url in browser `http://10.155.6.108:9292/downloads/EA0005632_000000000/abc.jpg`

What is the alternative way to access remote folder which is not shared?

Answer (score 0):

Remote folders cannot be accessed this way in Tomcat (or any other app-server). Remote folders need to be exposed via some service (like web service) on that host.